# Does Sidekiq supports retrying on separate queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Does Sidekiq supports the retrying on different queue as [Active job does](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on), cause looks like the only options available is using

`sidekiq_options :retry => 5`

I need that failed jobs went to another queue and being executed from there.

Looks like `sidekiq_options` does not have a lot of cases to configure.

I don't want to catch an exceptions and create a new job to new queue in manual way, I am looking for more transparent option for this.

P.S. I don't use ActiveJob right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify

```
sidekiq_options retry_queue: "some_other_queue"
```

The only place mentioning it is the changelog: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md#265

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this feature! I have updated the wiki here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration